# Creating a 2D array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Could also be called a 3D array, as each string is essentially it's own array.

Would be in the following format, each row = a new 'order'.

> [ [FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Newspaper] ]
>
> [ [FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Newspaper] ]

The contents of the array will be all strings (even though DOB would be in the format "23012017" and then converted to integer if necessary

---

Tried to use this "pointer arrays", but am not sure about how to use it.

`char *bookings[][2];`

`char firstname[20], secondname[20], dob[8];`

`char *bookings[][0]=firstname, *bookings[][1]=secondname, *bookings[][2]=dob;`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why not an array of structs?

Comment: Arrays should generally be used for uniform data. Use structs for heterogeneous information.

Comment: `char array3D[42][42][42]` would be a 2D array of strings (or a 3D array of char if you prefer). But I have a feeling that you want an array of a struct containing strings

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. You describe how you want to solve a problem but do not describe the real problem

Comment: The problem is that I need to store multiple bits of information from a users inputs.

Instead of storing details as multiple 2D arrays to be called from.

Comment: "tried to use this "pointer arrays" is not shown much in this question - post  enough of your code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a struct and a normal 1D array. Like:

```
struct order {
    char FirstName[42];
    char SecondName[42];
    char DOB[42];
    char Newspaper[42];
}
```

and in your code (e.g. in main)

```
struct order[42];
```

Then you do:

```
strcpy(order[0].FirstName, "Donald");
strcpy(order[0].SecondName, "Duck");
... and so on
```

Comment: Ahh, [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) - the answer to all buffer sizes and XY problems.

Comment: @chux Yes, that's it. The answer... ;-)